# External Relative Link in Sphinx toctree directive

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org) to build my documentation. I'm using other tool for API reference. I have my docs in a directory and the API reference in directory name api inside of it.

I want to have a link from the documentation to the API reference. I'm able to add a link to my toctree link so:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   starting
   glossary
   main-use-case-flow
   API Reference <http://www.example.com/lib/ios/0.1.0/api/>
```

The problem is I don't want to put a full path, I want to put just the relative path `api/`

How can I put a link to external resource using relative path and not absolute path?

Answer (score 35):

I found one of the hackiest ways possible to do this. Basically Sphinx allows either a path to a document or an absolute path that requires `http://`. It turns out all they do to validate your link is look for literally `http://`.

```
*WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'downloads'*
Downloads <../downloads>
```

But if you do:

```
Downloads <../downloads#http://>
```

No warning! This does mean however that when the user clicks on your link, it inserts the `http://` *fragment* or *named anchor* to your page link. If this is not a valid named anchor in your html, it will do nothing to your page (unless your page has some javascript that does something with the named anchor).

Comment: This is very sad but seems to be the only viable solution :(. It's really unfortunate that Sphinx doesn't support such a seemingly simple, often needed feature

Answer (score 12):

In the current version of Sphinx you can just put

```
.. toctree::

   Title <http://LINK>
```

and it will work.

Comment: This does not currently work with relative links: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/701

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem when I tried to add links to (generated) javadocs to my `toctree`.

My solution was to create a phony `index.rst` in the appropriate location within my source tree to satisfy the requirements of `toctree`.  I discovered the phony `index.rst` file must contain a title, so my file looked like this:

```
=======================
Java API (All Packages)
=======================
```

When you run `make`, this file gets copied into your build directory, `_build/html` (or whatever).

And then simply replace it with the *real* file after reStructuredText processing.

Comment: You can also use this, but with the `html_extra_path` setting in conf.py to have sphinx copy over files for you.

Answer (score -7):

The following syntax works for me:

```
`Page Title <../relative/path.html>`
```

Comment: Hi, I've checked but this didn't work insode ..toctree:: directive. I've got this error: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'`Page Title <../relative/path.html>`'

Comment: I only used that within a normal section, not in a toctree directive.